# Reading .txt for substrings, returning substrings for AutoCompleteSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I hit a roadblock trying to create an AutoCompletion for my textbox.

Attempt #1

```
string[] fileDB = Account.filedbContents;
string[] lines = { };
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@FILE_PATH)
while ((textboxWebsite.Text = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

Attempt #2

```
textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
autoComplete.AddRange()


string[] substrings = new string[] { textboxWebsite.Text };
substrings.SelectMany(substring => Enumerable.Range(0, ))
string line = File.Read(@"C:\Users\snogueir\Desktop\Coding\sandbox\keychainarray.txt");
}

AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
collection.AddRange(arr);

this.textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
```

Head is a bit fried. I am trying to make an AutoCompletion for whenever the user enters in a website into a textbox, it will try to find the most similar existing entry of the website in the
.txt file (imagine typing in 'face' in the textbox, would suggest 'facebook' if it exists)

```
website1=username1=password1
website2=username2=password2
website3=username3=password3
```

None of these compile.

I was thinking of using String.Split('='), but the only way I can think of doing that is by creating an individual array for literally every line and then returning credentialarray[0] (because that would be the website).

Help!

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the right track `string.split` is the simplest solution

but there are errors in your code.try this

```
        var lines = from a in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\snogueir\Desktop\Coding\sandbox\keychainarray.txt")
                    let b = a.Split('=').FirstOrDefault()
                    select b;

        textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        autoComplete.AddRange(lines.ToArray());           
        textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
```

Comment: One question though, I get a slight flickering when it iterates through the possibilities in order to fill in the autocomplete. If I were to use separate threads to handle the event, would it reduce the amount of flickering when searching? Maybe if I preload the file on a form-load event?

Comment: No I don't think multi-threading would solve the flickering issue.How big is the source file containing autocomplete data?

Comment: 386 bytes. I have a save button in the original application that appends to it, but being that it is for personal use I doubt it will ever get to more than ~40 lines long.

Comment: No it just means First element in the array returned by split method.or default value (null in this case) if array is empty

Comment: I found the problem.. sorry, this was handled by the textbox_textchanged event. Introducing the autocomplete settings with every keypress was bound to cause sluggish performance. it still flickers, but only slightly and is still tied to a textchanged event

Answer (score 2):

If you need the combination of website, username, and password to be stored together, I would create a simple class that can store those items, and which knows how to create itself by parsing one of your file lines, like so:

```
class FileEntry
{
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public static FileEntry Parse(string fileLine)
    {
        var result = new FileEntry();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileLine)) return result;

        var lineParts = fileLine.Split('=');

        result.Website = lineParts[0];
        if (lineParts.Length > 1) result.UserName = lineParts[1];
        if (lineParts.Length > 2) result.Password = lineParts[2];

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, when you parse your text file, you can just create one of these for every line and store them in a List. Then you can bind the `Website` property of each list item to your textbox's auto-complete:

```
// Store the list at the class level so other methods can access it:
private List<FileEntry> fileEntries;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\snogueir\Desktop\Coding\sandbox\keychainarray.txt";
    fileEntries = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(FileEntry.Parse).ToList();

    textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autoComplete.AddRange(fileEntries.Select(fe => fe.Website).ToArray());
    textboxWebsite.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
}
```

One benefit of this is that you now have a list that you can use to look up the username and password for whichever site they chose:

```
var userSelection = fileEntries.FirstOrDefault(fe =>
    fe.Website.Equals(textboxWebsite.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

var userName = userSelection?.UserName;
var password = userSelection?.Password;
```